# Why will Blender sometimes not select the object under the cursor

Tags: objects, selection-tools

How does Blender determine which object it selects when you right click in object mode?

I'm confused, because sometimes Blender won't select the object I'm clearly clicking on.

I made a video of one such situation for an example:

http://youtu.be/zmnRDUoOO5Y

In the video, I'm clearly clicking on top of the armature object, but Blender keeps selecting a different object that is not even under the mouse cursor.

Comment: This is not a bug, however this could be a feature request in that you would like to have the margin distance decreased/smartened. I have noticed the same issue, so I hope it gets addressed in the next release or so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is **margin distance** (in screen pixels) such that blender will select an object even if you click slightly next to it.

So that mesh gets selected instead of armature because it is on top of the armature and the pointer is within the margin area. When you zoom in the pointer is no longer in margin area and the armature is now the top most object.

Honestly blender could do picking much more smartly and also check if something is directly beneath pointer even if closer_to_camera mesh qualifies for selection.

Comment: Related: <https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?426150-Object-Selection-Accuracy>  
This was also driving me nuts so I searched the source code for answers. Turns out there's a massive 28 x 28 selection hitbox around the mouse cursor hard coded in to the select operator. It feels very clumsy and inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the object you want to select with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>. This will bring up a menu of objects close to the cursor. This is useful in situations where there are lots of objects on top of or close to each other.

[image]

Comment: alt+Rmb does not always work i just tried it and it would not show certain objects

Comment: I just tried in 2.77 and it works. Are you in object mode?